# Поле Date в заголовках письма

Tags: php

Что он делает и как им пользоваться?

P.S. Не нашел в Google примеров его использования и вообще, какого-то описания.

Comment: Установка даты отправки =)

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример использования. У меня почему-то не получается ее использовать.

Comment: Для начала, покажи, где ты такое видел, чтобы я смог сориентироваться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Формат почтового сообщения (RFC-822)](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/inet_server/servers_glava2_4.html)

> Поле Date определяет дату отправки сообщения, поле From - отправителя, а поля сс и To - получателя(ей). Чаще заголовок содержит дополнительные поля:
>
> ```
> Date:   26 Aug 76 1429 EDT
> From:   George Jones<Jones@Registry.org>
> Sender: Secy@SHOST
> To:     Smith@Registry.org
> Message-ID: <4231.629.XYzi-What@Registry.org>
> ```

Comment: +1 немного опередил меня

Comment: Попробовал, работает. Только вот я думал, что этот параметр работает как крон, иначе он зачем?..

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, дата подставляется сама, в момент отправки письма, это вам не крон.

Answer (score 0):

Вот описание данной функции [mail](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Про какой параметр Вы говорите?

Comment: "Second, the custom headers like From:, Cc:, Bcc: and Date: are not interpreted by..."

Comment: "Во-вторых, дополнительные заголовки вроде: From:, Cc:, Bcc: и Date: интерпретируются..." [Описание функции mail](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php).